# Google maps grey background when created with jQuery each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I was trying to simplify the way I add Google maps to my pages.

I'm using this markup for each map:

```
<div class="map" data-coordinates="-34.397, 150.644">
    <div class="canvas" id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

and this jquery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var maps = $('.map');

    maps.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            mapId = $this.find('.canvas').attr('id'),
            coordinates= $this.data('coordinates');

        // set map options
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // create the map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapId), mapOptions);
    });
});
```

this is a recreation of the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) on the google maps website.

when I do it like the tutorial it works fine, but when I use my code above I get the map controls with a grey background, I also tried `jQuery(window).load();` with the same result, and the issue seems to be from each() because when I create the map without it, it works fine.

this is the code that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem. Do you have dimensions set for `class="canvas"`?

Comment: @charlietfl I'll create one now, and the class canvas has width and height 100% which takes it's parent width and height set to 100%, 500px

Comment: There's a problem with `coordonates`. `google.maps.LatLng()` accepts `Lat` and `Lng` as separate params, not a composite string.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot you're right I didn't notice that, please submit an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with `coordonates`.

`google.maps.LatLng()` accepts Lat and Lng as separate params, not a composite string.

Try :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.map').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            canvas = $this.find('.canvas').get(0),
            coordinates = $this.data('coordinates').split(/,\s?/);

        // set map options
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(coordinates[0]), Number(coordinates[1])),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // create the map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, mapOptions);
    });
});
```

You might need to test that regexp.

Comment: even simpler you can pass array to `data-` attribute by simply wrapping values in `[]`, `data()` method will read it as array

Comment: same with object using `{}`